# Show that $K(x,z)$ is real in the Gelfand-Levitan Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

The Gelfand-Levitan equation is given as, $$F(x+y)+K(x,y)+\int_{x}^{\infty}K(x,z)F(y+z)dz=0$$
where $z = x+y$. I am trying to show that $K(x,z)$ is real, that is $K(x,z)^* = K(x,z)$.

$K(x,z)$ is defined as follows. We start with the Fourier transform of the function: $\psi(x,k)e^{ikx}-1$. Denote it as $A(x,y)$, that is $$A(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\psi(x,k)e^{ikx}-1) e^{iky}dk.$$
Here $x$ is just a parameter, and the transform is from $y$ to $k$. Using Jordans Lemma we can show that $A(x,y) = 0$ when $y<0$. So we can write using the inverse F-transform $$\psi-e^{-ikx} = \int_{0}^{\infty}A(x,y) e^{-iky}dy$$

Letting $z= x+y$ we can write $$\psi(x,k) = e^{-ikx}+\int_{x}^{\infty}K(x,z) e^{-ikz}dz$$ where $K(x,z) = A(x,z-x)$.

In the above $\psi$ is a solution to $L\psi = k^2\psi$ where $L$ is the Schrodinger operator, $L = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+u(x)$ and $\psi \rightarrow e^{-ikx}$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. Here $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ form a basis for the eigenfunctions of $L$.

Does anyone have any way to show that $K(x,z)$ is real? If you need clarification on any terms or notation, I'll provide them happily.

Comment: Typo? There does not seem to be an equality sign in your first display, not to mention that $f,F,K$ are not characterized in any way. Maybe a bit of rewriting would better convey what you want...

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have fixed the labeling and tried to explain more in my edit (if things still are not clear, please let me know). In fact the F term is not really relevant to the problem (besides that it appears in the Gelfand-Levitan equation).

Comment: Some edit-suggestions: "Schrodinger"... :)  ... and maybe tell what $\psi$ is up-top, so that the definition of $A(x,y)$ is clear, and then $K(x,z)=A(x,z-x)$ tells what $K$ is more directly. You could delay the context (that these are components in the Gelfand-Levitan equation) until toward the end, since your question seems fairly independent of that context. I hesitate to change things myself... since it is entirely possible that for someone else understanding your context better your presentation is as expected. Don't know! :)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am also new to this topic so I also don't know! :)

Comment: As Paul already pointed out, I think you're really providing way too much information that is completely irrelevant for what you're actually asking. You want to show that $A$ is real valued, and this follows at once from the observation that the integrand (let's call it $a(k)$) in the formula defining $A$ satisfies $a(-k)=\overline{a(k)}$ (since $\psi$ has this property). So the integral over $k<0$ is the complex conjugate of the part over $k>0$.

Comment: In all this, you will of course have to assume that the potential $u$ is rapidly decaying ($u\in L^1$ would work), or you won't have solutions $\psi$ with the desired asymptotics.